# Error while calling web service

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-volley

I am getting 400 error code when I try to call a web service using volley just after making around 8 API calls. This issue can be reproduced in 4.0.4 samsung galaxy tab. But it works fine in higher versions of android

**Error log:**

```
05-21 10:25:40.880    3947-3947/com.tc D/Volley? [1] DiskBasedCacheclear: Cache cleared.
05-21 10:25:40.890    3947-4028/com.tc I/qtaguid? Failed write_ctrl(t -1 2533528184876433408 -1) res=-1 errno=9
05-21 10:25:40.890    3947-4028/com.tc I/qtaguid? Tagging socket -1 with tag 2328e67600000000(-1557600650) for uid -1 failed errno=-9
05-21 10:25:40.890    3947-4028/com.tc I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger? tagSocketFd(-1, -1557600650, -1) failed with errno-9
05-21 10:25:41.160    3947-4028/com.tc I/qtaguid? Failed write_ctrl(t -1 2533528184876433408 -1) res=-1 errno=9
05-21 10:25:41.160    3947-4028/com.tc I/qtaguid? Tagging socket -1 with tag 2328e67600000000(-1557600650) for uid -1 failed errno=-9
05-21 10:25:41.160    3947-4028/com.tc I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger? tagSocketFd(-1, -1557600650, -1) failed with errno-9
05-21 10:25:41.430    3947-3947/com.tc E/TC? Web service tag: get_config_api_call
05-21 10:25:41.430    3947-3947/com.tc E/TC? onErrorResponse ----1com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 400
05-21 10:25:41.430    3947-3947/com.tc E/TC? onErrorResponse com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 400
```

For testing purpose I replaced volley call with an httpurlconnection and I got a similar error.

**Error log:**

```
-21 13:05:33.080    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 400
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeTunnel(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:508)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
05-21 13:05:33.150    2515-2801/com.tc W/System.err? at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
```

I have noticed that this issue occurs only in those scenarios in which API is called just after making multiple requests. If I simply call it after commenting the multiple requests before it, then it will work properly.

Comment: It's impossible to find the source of this problem with knowing how the server behaves.

Comment: @Egor: Is this issue related to server? I have tried to test it with other android devices (4.4, 5.0, 4.2) and there is no issue.

Comment: At least it would be good to know in which situations the server returns 400.